# How to load file from the Bundle in eclipse & My Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

This is very strange behavior I have noticed while developing Plugin.
I have a file in the bundle that has to be loaded for wizard.
I tried to load the file in eclipse using following code.

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(MTPAppPlugin.getDefault()
                .getBundle().getSymbolicName());
        URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry(relativeFilePath);
        File file = new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).toURI());
```

But this didnt worked in MyEclipse.So I used other way for my eclipse

```
url = new URL("platform:/plugin/"
                + MTPAppPlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getSymbolicName()
                + relativeFilePath);
        InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Now I need to know is there any common way to load the file for eclipse & My Eclipse?

Comment: If you don't switch to a file, the first way will work as well.  Once you have the URL, just turn it into an InputStream similar to your option 2.

Answer (score 1):

The first one will not work if you have space in your folder path like C:\program files....

Comment: Thanks... The second way worked in both eclipse & my Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems to be correct. What was the error given in MyEclipse?

Comment: My Eclipse was unable to load the files from the bundle.